# Initial setup: Google Assistant isn't available for this account

Tags: google-account, activation

Getting the following error when I try to active my new One Plus 7 Pro,

[image: screenshot of problem]

> **The Google Assistant isn't available for this account**
>
> The Google Assistant needs Activity controls that your device administrator has limited on this account. Check with your administrator or switch accounts and try again

Comment: You used to be able to skip this step and simply not set up Google assistant, but it seems like that's no longer allowed? Getting the same on a Galaxy S10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I had to do was

1. Log into https://admin.google.com
2. Click "Apps"
3. Click "Additional Google Services"
4. Click "Web & App activity"
5. Select ON For Everyone
6. Confirm

Comment: in my situation this did not help as it was already set to that :( any other ideas out there?

Comment: I didn't have "Web & App activity" and it wasn't in the list to add.

Comment: Here is a direct link to the Google Admin page: https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#AppsList:serviceType=ADDITIONAL&appsFilter=ALL&ca=NONE